# How is the efficiency of Test-Path affected by using the -PathType parameter?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, powershell-v6.0

Does using the `-PathType` argument to specify a Leaf or Container have any impact on the efficiency of the `Test-Path` cmdlet?

More an academic question as I can't imagine any gain here being anything other than negligible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a high level, specifying `-PathType Leaf` adds slight overhead to the `Test-Path` operation because it has to test *2 things* rather than one - that the item exists *and* that it's not a container.

In the end, the performance impact depends heavily on the underlying provider. The `FileSystem` provider is pretty quick to determine whether an existing item is a container type, but there's no guarantee that that's the case for all providers - it comes down to the nature of the underlying data store and implementation details

Comment: Thanks, the provider is FileSystem so shouldn't really make a difference. In this case I was thinking it would be better to be explicit to improve reliability, there's already a check for file extension using -Include so maybe that's overkill? As I understand from your answer that would add additional overhead again rather than reducing it.

Comment: @Mackles Unless calling `Test-Path` is >50% of what you're doing, I wouldn't worry too much about the performance aspect of it :-) It's negligble, and anything you win, you'll have to pay back in spades when your function/script one day fails in unexpected ways

Answer (score 0):

I ran the following code:

```
$result1 = measure-command {
    for ($i = 1; $i -lt 101; $i++)
    { 
         test-path C:\windows\temp     
    }
}
```

I then ran:

```
$result2 = measure-command {
    for ($i = 1; $i -lt 101; $i++)
    { 
         test-path C:\windows\temp -PathType leaf      
    }
}
```

Interestingly `$result1` was 31 milliseconds where as `$result2` was 36 milliseconds.  It seems that adding the `-pathtype leaf` does add overhead but unless you are testing ALOT of paths it should be negligible.